# MoltenVK driver calls the wrong functions for some Vulkan function calls

Tags: vulkan

I'm trying to use Vulkan on MacOS, with the eventual goal of making a cross platform program. My program worked when I statically linked MoltenVK (with the vulkan headers copied into it).

My current setup statically links vulkan.framework, and uses an ICD to load libMoltenVK.dylib. This initially appeared to work: in the logs, I can see "INFO: Found ICD manifest file [expected path to my manifest file]". All the extensions I expect are then found and listed, including `VK_KHR_surface`. I enable it when I create my `VkInstance`.

I can call various vulkan functions successfully, including `vkCreateMacOSSurfaceMVK`. However, when I try to call `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR`, my program crashes.

With no validation layers, it seems like vulkan loads the wrong function: the next symbol in the call stack is `vkCreateQueryPool` instead of the expected `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR`, and MoltenVK prints `[***MoltenVK ERROR***] VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED: vkCreateQueryPool: Unsupported query pool type: -1094795586`. The program crashes on the next vulkan call, which happens to be `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR`, but which actually calls into `MVKDevice::destoryQueryPool`.

With validation layers on, the program crashes on `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR`, which tries to call `0x0`. There are no errors printed about validation failing for any of them.

I tried turning on Dynamic Linker API usage/ Dynamic Library loads in Xcode's scheme editor, but I didn't find the information they provided helpful.

Why would vulkan/dyld not hook up some functions correctly? How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

You are actually using the Vulkan Loader, not an "ICD", to load libMoltenVK.dylib.  libMoltenVK.dylib itself is considered an Installable Client Driver (ICD).

Are you using `vkGetInstanceProcAddr()` to get the function address of `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR()` ?  The Vulkan Loader only exports the core (and some WSI) functions.  You'll need to get the addresses of other extension functions with `vkGetInstanceProcAddr()`.

See this [code](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Tools/blob/master/vulkaninfo/vulkaninfo.c) for an example of using GIPA.  Search for "vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR".  `vulkaninfo` calls this extension successfully on MacOS.

I suspect that the MoltenVK lib exports this extension function directly, which is why it worked when you statically linked MoltenVK.  Also, when using the Vulkan loader, you should not be linking the MoltenVK library to your application.  The Vulkan loader loads it for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work in my case. The function returned from `vkGetInstanceProcAddr()` is the same one I get if I just call `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR` directly. I also tried dlopening MoltenVK.dylib and hooking it up with dlsym myself as a sanity check: I got a pointer to MVKPhysicalDevice::getSurfaceCapabilities. It crashes in objc_msgsend when called, but I assume that's a separate issue.

Comment: Without seeing more code, it almost looks like you are passing a wrong or bad physical device to `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR`.

The Vulkan SDK for MacOS has a Getting Started guide that shows you how to load up the `vulkaninfo` client into Xcode.  It may be worth looking at that as a working example.